# Do I Say morning blessing twice If I fell asleep again?

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot

If I washed my hands and did the morning blessing although later I went to sleep for like a couple hours 3-4 maybe less do I have to say the morning blessing of washing hands again after I wake up?

Comment: Which morning blessing are you referring to?

Comment: This sounds like what most people call "taking a nap", yes?

Comment: @JoelK blessing of washing hands

Comment: @DoubleAA yes although do I have to say the blessing of washing hands after I wake up

Answer (score 2):

Although one washes his hands each time he awakens from a substantial sleep, he only says the blessing of *al netillat yadayim* once.

This is certainly true if he has a nap during the day ([Shulchan Aruch Orach Chaim 4:15](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.4.15?lang=bi)).

What about if one arises early (before dawn) washes his hands and says the blessing, and then goes back to sleep while it is still dark? In such a case, [Mishnah Berurah 4:32](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishnah_Berurah.4.32?lang=bi) rules that although he must wash again when he wakes up a second time, he does not say the blessing again.